# Pandas nunique got an expected

Tags: python, pandas, count

I'm trying to learn Pandas and I'm running into a small problem with `groupby` and `nunique`.

Creating the dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

chicago_dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gjreda/gregreda.com/master/content/notebooks/data/city-of-chicago-salaries.csv" ,
                                  converters={'Employee Annual Salary': lambda x: float(x.replace('$', ''))})
```

With the headers:

```
chicago_dataset.columns
Out[63]: Index(['Name', 'Position Title', 'Department', 'Employee Annual Salary'], dtype='object')
```

Now I want to group by `Department` and get a distinct count of `Position Title` how would I do something like this?

```
by_dept = chicago_dataset.groupby('Department')
```

I can do it with `Name` like below but `Position Title` is two words.

```
by_dept.Name.nunique()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two different ways to do it:

1. `df.valid_python_name`
2. `df['any string with spaces and # etc.']`

Use the second:

```
by_dept['Position Title'].nunique()
```

Example:

```
>>> by_dept['Position Title'].nunique().head()

Department
ADMIN HEARNG          15
ANIMAL CONTRL         19
AVIATION             125
BOARD OF ELECTION     23
BOARD OF ETHICS        9
Name: Position Title, dtype: int64
```